# (HTML, CSS ) Is default property value of color attribute in <a> tag is black?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
    color: green;
}
          
.my-class-1 a {
    color: inherit;
}
          
.my-class-2 a {
    color: initial;
}
          
.my-class-3 a {
    color: unset;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Default <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
    <li class="my-class-1">Inherit the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
    <li class="my-class-2">Reset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
    <li class="my-class-3">Unset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
</ul>
```

I'm getting help at MDN site. (https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance)

What I can't understand is my-class-2 a rulesets in css.
the property value of color attribute is set to initial.
Initial value sets the property value applied to a selected element to the initial value of that property.
When I see it, the  tag text color belonged to .my-class-2 class displayed **black**.
Isn't default property value of color attribute in  tag is **blue**?
I don't know what's happening.

I want to know default property value of color attribute in  tag isn't blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- "The initial value of each property is indicated in the property's definition" [[specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#specified-value)].
- The `initial` value of the `color` property is defined as `CanvasText` [[specification](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-color/#the-color-property)].
- The exact value of `CanvasText` may be defined "by the user, the browser, or the OS" [[specification](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-color/#css-system-colors)].

Usually, `CanvasText` is defined as black or a similarly dark color. If a user sets their browser and/or OS to dark mode, `CanvasText` may, however, be defined as white or a similarly light color.

Answer (score 0):

The `initial` value of the `color` property is browser-dependent (so that's mostly black). `Initial` means browser default, that’s how this property has been defined.

Answer (score 0):

Since the parent element of a is green, `unset` will set the color to green

`unset` will favor legacy values ​​over browser values

`initial` will set all to default color (black)